# Python aiohttp discord failing to start function

Tags: python, discord, aiohttp

So, I'm trying to create a API with aiohttp that if you do /?state=start, it will call the my_Bot() function and start the bot itself. It is giving me multiple errors with a bunch of different ways I have tried. I have both the start/index function and my_Bot function async'ed and it is giving this error

`RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'my_Bot' was never awaited my_Bot() RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

This is the code for the Python file. The index function is for loading the request and starting the bot and the my_Bot function is for actually loading/starting the Discord bot instance

````
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import asyncio


load_dotenv()

app = web.Application()

async def index(request):
    state = request.rel_url.query['state']
    if state == 'start':
        my_Bot()
        return web.json_response({'state': 'Online'})
    return web.FileResponse('index.html')

app.router.add_get('/', index)
app.router.add_get('/index', index)
app.router.add_get('/index.html', index)

async def get_token(request):
    token = os.getenv('TOKEN')
    return web.json_response({'token': token})

app.router.add_get('/token', get_token)

async def my_Bot():
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands

    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', self_bot=True)

    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        print('Logged in as')
        print(bot.user.name)
        print(bot.user.id)
        print('------')

    @bot.command()
    async def ping(ctx):
        await ctx.send('pong')

    bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #my_Bot()
    web.run_app(app)```
````

Answer (score 0):

yeah because u typed async def my_bot so u should await it

you can make a function to run the bot asynchronously

```
async def main():
    await my_Bot()
    web.run_app(app)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```